# SELINUX sysadm_u and SSH - Unable to get valid context for username

Tags: linux, selinux, rhel7

Once I set user usernameto sysadm_u they are no longer able to login via SSH and receive the error: `Unable to get valid context for username`

Commands

```
semanage login -m -s sysadm_u username
semanage login -a -s sysadm_u username
restorecon -RF /home/username
```

When I run `ausearch -m AVC -m USER_AVC -m SELINUX_ERR` I get the following:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1590015667.658:4996): avc:  denied  { noatsecure } for  pid=7424 comm="bash" scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:system_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=process permissive=0
type=AVC msg=audit(1590015667.658:4996): avc:  denied  { siginh } for  pid=7424 comm="bash" scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:system_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=process permissive=0
```

For here I am lost as how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by `sudo setsebool -P ssh_sysadm_login on`

See: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1814549